# GORM,get org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection when open transaction in afterLoad()

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

```
class A {
  def afterLoad() {
    A.withTransaction {

    }
  }
}
```

Most case, it works, until I call below list in controller

```
A.createCriteria().list{.....}
```

will throw exception:org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection

If I remove

```
A.withTransaction
```

It will then works.

Answer (score 1):

may be

```
A.withNewSession { session ->
  ....
}
```

will help you

Comment: I didn't try, I need transaction in these code. Now my walk around is add A.withTransaction around the list{...} code. But I want to know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this exception myself and I was really stumped on it for a few days.  You can see if the solution to this question solves your problem:

[HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318692/hibernateexception-found-two-representations-of-same-collection)

That solution didn't work for me, so I wrote an article describing the issue and what I did to solve it that [you can read here](http://machineversus.me/2012/08/hibernateexception-found-two.html).  I believe your problem is similar to mine because of the transactional aspect, Hibernate is flushing the session when the transaction is committed and that's where the exception is thrown.