# HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

If I save an object containing the following list

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="taskList")
@OrderColumn(name="position", nullable=false)
public List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
```

I get the exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection
```

The code in the Play! controller looks like this:

```
TaskList taskList = taskList.findById(taskListId);
taskList.add(position, task);
taskList.save();
```

If I insert `taskList.refresh()` before this block it works, but the position information is lost (which leads to other errors).

Is this a Hibernate bug or is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was, that Hibernate does not support the combination of `@OneToMany(mappedBy=...)` and `@OrderColumn`. Without `mappedBy` Hibernate uses a join table and everything works as expected. See [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480336/238134).

Answer (score 2):

The same error occurs when you try to modify an associated collection of an object.   e.g.:

```
    MyObject myObject = myObjectService.get(id);
    List<Task> newTasks = //populate new list of Task here
    myObject.setTasks(newTasks);
    myObjectService.saveOrUpdateObject(myObject); // or merge(myObject)
```

In such a case, it can be resolved by:

```
    MyObject myObject = myObjectService.get(id);
    List<Task> newTasks = //populate new list of Task here
    myObject.setTasks(new List<Task>); // or myObject.getTasks().clear();
    myObject.getTasks().addAll(newTasks);
    myObjectService.merge(myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve the issue by changing the association to `lazy` and removing the cascade.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="taskList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderColumn(name="position", nullable=false)
public List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
```

Comment: Removing FetchType.EAGER worked for while retaining the CascadeType.ALL operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the list to be persisted you might need to annotate your list with @OneToMany to be able to persist your entity.

Comment: You are right. I left out this annotation to shorten my example - probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for the exception "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection" is duplicated getters/setters in the entity.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hours I found the solution, I had the same problem.

I had an EntityListener with this code in my Spring Boot app

```java
@PostLoad
public void defineRelation(EntityWithRelation entityWithRelation) {
        entityWithRelation.setRelation(objectRelationBo
                .findOneByObjectTypeAndReferenceId(entityWithRelation.getObject(), entityWithRelation.getId()));
}
```

This was causing the exception in a random (or looks like) collection of other unrelated entity that was participating in the same transaction. I don't know the exact reason but adding `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` fixes the problem

Maybe Hibernate doesn't like you to modify the entity by hand, but the field was a transient field...

Answer (score -1):

the problem is with your joining check whether you are not fatching any data which is not in the table