# Hibernate Code Checker

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

Does anyone know of a plugin or tool that would check for validity of Hibernate usage in Java classes?

For example, warn when an entity is missing a no-arg constructor?  The Eclipse IDE has a Hibernate tool, but it's mostly about generating the config files.

Answer (score 0):

You have [Eclipse Dali persistence tool](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/downloads.php), but it check for JPA valid usage (like, valid relation, entities referenced in `persistence.xml`, with a primary key, and against the database, ...). It probably has what you want (checking no arg constructor).

The plugin name (if you search in Updates) : Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA Support

Comment: That's not bad, but nothing specifically for Hibernate though?  There are other things like the accepted answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318692/hibernateexception-found-two-representations-of-same-collection.  If a tool would find things like this before runtime, it could saves lots of time and headache.

Comment: There was jboss tools and hibernate tools: http://hibernate.org/tools/ I used it only once, but I don't remember seeing such checks.